# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'long'

Tags: c#

I have two tables in my MS Sql database, Course and StudyCase, with a FK ID (Course table) to Course_ID (in the StudyCase table).  I am trying to find the StudyCase ID from the Course id.

In the Repository:

```
  public IQueryable<StudyCase> ListStudyCases(long courseId)
        {
            return _dbContext.StudyCases.Where(c => c.Course_ID == courseId);
        }
```

In the StudyCases Services:

```
public IQueryable<StudyCase> ListStudyCases(long courseId)
    {
        return this._StudyCaseRepository.ListStudyCases(courseId);
    }
```

In the StudyCases IServices:

```
 IQueryable<StudyCase> ListStudyCases(long courseId);
```

Sending the action from the course controller:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "CourseCases", new { courseId = 6 });
```

In the StudyCase Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(long courseId)
        {
            string id = "";
            id = _studyCaseSvc.ListStudyCases(courseId).First().ID.ToString();
            StudyCase cases = _studyCaseSvc.GetStudyCase(id);
...
```

I get the following two error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'long'
```

and

```
The best overloaded method match for 'IStudyCaseService.GetStudyCase(long)' has some invalid arguments
```

Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use your action argument without converting it to string.

```
public ActionResult Index(long courseId)
    {
        var id = _studyCaseSvc.ListStudyCases(courseId).First().ID;
        StudyCase cases = _studyCaseSvc.GetStudyCase(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `id` as a string, If you want to use it as an argument for `GetStudyCase`, it needs to be a `long`.  If you want to pass a string, then `GetStudyCase` should have an overload that accepts a string.

I'm new to MVC, but this seems more like a general C# question than specifically relating to MVC.